# Codeigniter not showing pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I have made a codigniter controller named 'Controller' which I have set us the default controller, however when i try to access a different function inside that controller eg. blog it just shows the home page...

I haven't made any router changes apart from the default controller.

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't name your controller 'Controller'

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html

Comment: But that would mean actually reading the documentation. -1 (just kidding)

Comment: I have renamed it to home, but still doesn't work... I have set the uri_protocol as 'ORIG_PATH_INFO' if that makes any difference

Comment: Turns it was an htaccess issue